# How to serve ionic app with https?

Tags: ssl, https, ionic-framework, ionic2

Running ionic serve (`ionic serve --lab`) allows to run the app on http://localhost:8100/ionic-lab

Trying to access https://localhost:8100/ionic-lab results in:

> SSL connection error

Is there a way to run the app on https?

I followed the instructions from the [link](https://certsimple.com/blog/localhost-ssl-fix) to overcome SSL error,  but couldn't figure out how to use it with ionic (i.e. I don't know how to use `cert.pem` & `key.pem` files while starting the server with the command `ionic serve --lab`)

Comment: not gonna mark my answer as correct?

Answer (score 2):

use `--ssl` option:

```
ionic serve --lab --ssl
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried the steps from the official [Github issues thread](https://github.com/driftyco/ionic/issues/1686)?

> To create a self signed cert and run it with a go proxy script
>   https://gist.github.com/scrivy/0909468fde8f117a3d66507c8bb3fe12